# Changing full-width background color for contain Bootstrap Nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, background-color

> Hey everyone!
>
> Ultimately I want to change the color of the navigation bar to #333
>   full width, while still having the content (links) of the navigation
>   contained (not full width).
>
> Here is the code:
>
> HTML

```
<!-- navbar -->
>     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
>         <div class="container">
>             <div class="navbar-header">
>                 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
>                     aria-controls="navbar">
>             <span class="sr-only">Navigation</span>
>             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>           </button>
>             </div>
>             <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
>                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
>                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
>                     <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
>                     <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
>                     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
>                     <li><a href="#">Broadcast</a></li>
>                     <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
>                     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
>                 </ul>
>             </div>
>             <!--/.nav-collapse -->
>         </div>
>     </nav>
>     <!--end of navbar-->
> 
> 
> 
> CSS
> 
> .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
>     border: 0;
>     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
>     box-shadow: none; }
> 
> .navbar {
>     margin-bottom: 0 !important;   }
>
```

> Any help would be awesome as I'm stuck!
>
> Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #333 !important;
   
}

.navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color:#FFF !important;
    }
```

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="navbar-header">
                 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"aria-controls="navbar">
                     
             <span class="sr-only">Navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
             </div>
             <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Broadcast</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             <!--/.nav-collapse -->
         </div>
     </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but, it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: updated fiddle, have a look https://jsfiddle.net/girish28892/dgt9zzof/1/

Comment: Thanks for uploading that...it's funny, in dreamweaver it seems to accept the bkgnd color change...but when i view it in a browser the background still  appears white.

Comment: hit "Ctrl+F5" on browser, may be it is loading from your cache

Comment: Hmm...still doesn't work....is it being effected by a bootstrap standard css code?

Comment: Update ^^: I deleted all the content from the html and css files and just included standard bootstrap min css's and then inputted new html and css code as suggested to see if there was a conflict in my code...

this still didnt work.